# Stored procedure that calls another stored procedure filters columns by partial name, then compares the second SP's return number with column amounts

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

The goal is to get the amount of passwords the user has, compare it with the company's rules. If it exceeds the number they allow, we insert the new one (with the date) and delete the last one (or delete the last one then insert the new one.  I honestly have figured out which way I want to go yet).

I have two stored procedures: `Delete_Oldest_Password_And_Date` and `Number_Of_Passwords`

`Delete_Oldest_Password_And_Date` calls `Number_Of_Passwords` because I need that amount.

I'm pretty sure the beginning of my stored procedure is good. It's the second half, starting with `@Temp_Password_Table`.

```
CREATE Procedure Delete_Oldest_Password_And_Date
    @ua_pk uniqueidentifier
AS
    DECLARE @Temp_Table table
    (
        numberOfPasswords INT
    )

    INSERT INTO @Temp_Table
    EXEC Number_Of_Passwords @ua_pk
    SELECT *    
    FROM
        @Temp_Table

    DECLARE @Temp_Password_Table table
    (
    password varchar(max)
    )

    SELECT *
    FROM User_Passwords
    WHERE User_Passwords.ua_fk = @ua_pk
    AND up_Password LIKE '%Password%'

GO

GRANT EXEC ON Delete_Oldest_Password_And_Date TO WEB

GO
```

I'm not worried about the delete just yet. I'm more worried about getting the correct information first.

Keep in mind User_Passwords is dynamic per person. The plan (I haven't gotten to this part yet) is to have the newest go into a column named "up_Password1", then the second newest into column "up_Password2", etc.

Comment: sorry about that!  corrected!

Comment: Is there only one value returned from Number_of_Passwords? If it's just going to be a single INT value each time I'd just place this in a INT variable, not a table variable. Then you could use it with an IF/ELSE block more cleanly

Comment: Hi again!  Yes, one value, an INT from one field (cell)

Comment: I tried doing that too, but I was most likely doing it incorrectly.  It was throwing errors

Comment: So User_Passwords has a variable number of columns, depending on the user and how many previous passwords they have?

Comment: Correct.  So a new user could have 1 password and the company they work for doesn't want any duplicate password within the past 10 (super long story, but that's where all of this is going, not allowing duplicate previous passwords).  So, while an older user could have all 10 filled up.  Or another user for another company might only want five passwords to save.

Comment: I would think a better implementation of the passwords table would be one where each row represents a single password, perhaps with a user id, password field/hash, start date, and end date. Variable numbers of columns will be more difficult to work with. And then you wouldn't need a stored proc to get them number of previous passwords. you'd simple do a SELECT COUNT(*) FROM User_Passwords WHERE ua_fk = @ua_pk.

Comment: I'm seriously building this ground up, so I can do that.  New job = new languages.  I can do the row idea.

Comment: so:     SELECT COUNT(up_Password)
    FROM User_Passwords
    WHERE User_Passwords.ua_fk = @ua_pk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a proc that will check the number of passwords a user has, and will delete the oldest password(s) until there are Max#ofPasswords-1, thus setting up for a new password to be inserted that still follows the policy for number of historical passwords. The proc assumes the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.User_Passwords(
    ua_fk UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    password_hash NVARCHAR(100),
    start_date DATETIME,
    end_date DATETIME)
```

Password_hash can be whatever you decide to store the password column as (just please don't store actual passwords in plain text here).

```
CREATE Procedure Delete_Oldest_Password_And_Date
    @ua_pk uniqueidentifier
AS
    DECLARE @numberOfPasswords INT,
            @MaxPasswordNum INT = 10

    SELECT @numberOfPasswords = COUNT(*)    
    FROM User_Passwords
    WHERE ua_fk = @ua_pk

    IF @numberOfPasswords >= @MaxPasswordNum
    BEGIN
        WITH T
        AS (SELECT TOP (@numberOfPasswords - (@MaxPasswordNum-1)) *
            FROM   User_Passwords
            WHERE  ua_fk = @ua_pk
            ORDER BY end_date ASC)
        DELETE FROM T; 
    END

GO
```

Comment: Just for clarification, if a user has 5 passwords, there would be 5 different records in User_Passwords using this schema.

Comment: Excellent!  .....I actually didn't want you to add the delete because I wanted to stumble through that but thank you!